# Modern name or translation of the illness "der rothen Sucht"

Tags: meaning, translation, history, kurrent

I'm trying to translate an old family bible from the 1870s and stumbled upon a cause of death of a child that I'm struggling with.
The writing is in an old handwriting (Sütterlin?) so it's a bit of guesswork and it's not made easier by not being a native speaker... but I think it says

> Den 7. Oktober 1870 ist uns das Kind Christina gestorben an der rothen Sucht

[image: Picture of a handwritten page from the 1870s]

I also found a reference to the same illness on archive.org though (https://archive.org/stream/hufelandsjourna47unkngoog/hufelandsjourna47unkngoog_djvu.txt) so I'm pretty sure the spelling is correct.

I have no idea what modern illness this translates to though. (Also if some kind soul can read this terrible script and want to transcribe the rest of the page I won't complain :P)

Comment: I amazed that how anyone could compreehend anything from this. I can't see any letter.s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have no idea how you were able to decipher that as a non-native speaker. Good work! Yes, it's some kind of Kurrentschrift. Sütterlin was another type of Kurrentschrift, but it wasn't created until 1911.

*Rote Sucht* or *Rotsucht* should be measels (Masern), or maybe rubella (Röteln). See for example [this list of diagnostic codes](https://www.med-kolleg.de/icd/R/24144.htm) or [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=dtaxl&q=rotsucht). [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/sucht) also mentions "Scharlach" (scarlet fever). There was prevalent use in Schwaben (Swabia).

Attempt of a transcription:

> Den 7. Oktober 1870 ist uns das
> Kind Christine gestorben an
> der rothen Sucht. Text Es ist noch
> eine Ruh vorhanden dem Volk
> Gottes. Grab Schrift. Wohl dir
> du liebes Kind, weil dich schon die
> Engel Gottes leiten, nun darfst 
> du droben selig ruhn, und durch 
> die Himmel schreiten, fahre hin

"Es ist noch eine Ruh vorhanden" is the beginning of a church chant.

The Grabschrift is also a slightly altered chant. From [*Evangelischer Liederschatz für Kirche, Schule und Haus*](https://www.google.de/books/edition/Evangelischer_Liederschatz_f%C3%BCr_Kirche_S/oltFAAAAcAAJ?hl=de&gbpv=1&dq=%22nun%20darfst%20du%20droben%20selig%20ruhn%22&pg=PA1224&printsec=frontcover):

[image: Wohl Dir, oh Todter, weil dich nun]

Comment: The book at archive.org has this badly OCRed piece of text

>> «BgebUch  an  der  rothen  Sucht  (MorbiI{en)  ge^ storben  seyen <<

and "Morbilli" is apparently another name for measels which I didn't know so you are most probably correct.

Comment: Regarding the desiphering... A solid C-something language proficiency and lots of patience. Thanks for the encouragement :)

Comment: Such heartbreaking examples make you think that Pinker has a point... our children simply don't die from Measles any longer, period.

Comment: The diagnostic distinction between measles, rubella and scarlet fever is difficult, if you only have the outer signs to go by. Rubella being a distinct disease seperate from measles or scarlet fever [found international recognition in 1881](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubella#History). Scarlet fever being a bacterial infection also was only [established durung the 19th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scarlet_fever#History). I don't think these scientific dicussions had much impact on the popular understanding of "red diseases" - it could have been any of them.

Comment: The modern diagnostic term for all of them seems to be [Infectious Exanthem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exanthem).

Answer (score 3):

(This actually rehashes remarks by OP in comments to a different answer:)

The Hufeland source actually provides the solution on printed page 92, first line:

> an  der rothen  Sucht  (Morbillen) gestorben seyen.

This can be resolved by reference works of this time as [Brockhaus 1894](http://www.retrobibliothek.de/retrobib/schlagwort.html?wort=Masern&werk=Brockhaus) to correspond to **Masern** (measles) today.

Answer (score 2):

German Wikipedia has a list of historical illness names, but *Rote Sucht* does not appear there.

My guess would be that *Rote Sucht* means scarlet fever (Scharlach in German). But measles also appears plausible.